# Sum of squares of iid Normal distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

What distribution for iid Standardized Normal Distributions $X_i \sim N(0,1),i=1,\ldots,n$
has **this distribution**
$$X_1^2+\ldots+X_n^2?$$

What role does **independence** play there? Thank you.

Comment: I think it is Chi Squared?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution zzzzzzzzz

Comment: Oh and if you want some more details on various normals, read http://nitro.biosci.arizona.edu/courses/EEB600A/download/Distributions.pdf

Comment: Independence plays an essential role. If it is not demanded then e.g. you could have $X_1=\cdots=X_n$ resulting in the distribution of $nX_1^2$ which is (if $n>1$) not a chi-squared distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment:** The following information is scattered in various of the references mentioned in previous Comments. Here, one one page, is the outline of a proof that for $n$ independent $X_i \sim \mathsf{Normal}(0,1),$ one has $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n).$

First, show that $X_1^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(1).$ One method is to find
the density of $|X_i|,$ with support $(0, \infty).$ Then use elementary
transformation to find that $X_1^2$ has the PDF of $\mathsf{Chisq}(1).$

Next, use PDF's to find the MGF's $M_X(t) = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{1/2}}$ of $X_1$ and
$M_Q(t) = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{n/2}}$ of $\mathsf{Chisq}(n),$ for $t < 1/2.$

Finally, use the multiplicative property of MGFs to recognize that $[M_X(t)]^n = M_Q(t).$

Comment: Are you sure with the ineqality $t > 1/2$ ? The term $(1-2t)$ then gets **negative**!

Comment: Typo fixed. Thanks.